# FactoryGirl Without Cleaning?

Tags: rspec, factory-bot

Anyone know of a way to use FactoryGirl without cleaning the database at all? In other words using factories whilst leaving existing records completely intact? EDIT: Attempts to do so produce a database error because the new ID collides with an existing ID in the database.

I imagine the biggest problem would be getting FG to use the database's underlying sequences/auto-increment capabilities. (Bad data from previous test failures do not concern me.)

This is similar to [Rspec/FactoryGirl: clean database state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323239/rspec-factorygirl-clean-database-state) but I'm open to any approach.

Answer (score 0):

The standard RSpec behavior for Rails apps is to roll back database transactions after each example. This can be configured in `spec/rails_helper`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # 
  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  #
end
```

Setting `use_transactional_fixtures` to `false` will stop RSpec from rolling back the test database transactions. Normally this is done to allow Database Cleaner to manage the test database with `DatabaseCleaner.clean`, but if you remove Database Cleaner (or leave out the cleaning step), the newly created entries will simply pile up as you run more tests.

This doesn't seem like a particularly good idea--you would almost certainly be better off recreating the necessary database state for each example, even at the cost of slower tests.

Comment: I've tried excluding DatabaseCleaner yet still get collisions with existing primary keys when it tries to assign 1 to the first factory-created row. (Updating question to highlight this problem.)

Answer (score 0):

So FactoryGirl already works with the database's underlying sequences/auto-increment values as long as one does not explicitly define such a column in the factory definition.